# How to print the value of unicode character with unicodedata?

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to print unicode characteres in loop:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', '\u00a{i}')
```

But this caused the next error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-4: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

However the wanted result is:

```
¡
¢
£
¤
...
```

Do you have some ideas how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`chr(i)`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#chr) ("Return the string representing a character whose Unicode code point is the integer `i`.") instead of string-formatting things.

```
>>> for i in range(0, 10):
...     print(chr(0xa0 + i))
...

¡
¢
£
¤
¥
¦
§
¨
©
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works, but I should work with the next unicode format "\u00.."

Comment: @IKKLX you can't do what you want by trying to format `\u00a{i}` because python evaluates the `\uxxxx` escape as a character _before_ any formatting happens.

Comment: @AKX I have in text this unicode characteres **\uxxxx** and I should replace them with appropriate value. But also I had in text **'\n'** characters, but they hould stay without replacing. Do you have some suggestions? Because what I tried neither works or replace even **''\n'** characters.

Comment: @IKKLX: `chr` is the function which convert Unicode codepoints to characters. To use `{i}` you need the `f`-string prefix. But `\uxxxx` is an escape: it is translate then code is loaded. But his happens much earlier that the code is executed (and so before the `for`)